# prevent yas from inserting a new-line after expansion

Tags: yasnippet

So I'm doing a recursive snippet with yas

```
$>name: "${2:`(file-name-nondirectory (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)))`}"${3:,
$>np}$0
```

but yas inserts a new-line at the end of every snippet, and after a while, it looks like this:

```
foo: {
    name: "bar",
    name: "bar",
    name: "bar",
    name: "bar",




}
```

how do I stop this?

Comment: Maybe this applies: [Yasnippet FAQ - Why is there an extra newline?](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/faq.html#org64f1b8c)

Comment: I thought I had already check this possibility ut apparently not. thx